# Zend Framework: Route assemble and GET parameters

Tags: zend-framework, routes

In my Bootstrap I have

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':language/:country/:controller/:action/*', 
    array(
        'language' => 'en',
        'country' => 'us',
        'controller' => 'bicycle',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'language' => '[a-z][a-z]',
        'country' => '[a-z][a-z]'
    )
);
```

Somewhere in my view I have

```
echo $this->url(array('page'=>2));
//actually this translated to $route->assemble(array('page' => 2), null, false);
```

The problem, is when I have some GET parameters: they won't be considered in the building of the link, and this is what I actually want.

Example:
I access the URL (in the browser)

```
http://localhost/myproject/en/us/controller/action/?get1=gval1&get2=gval2&get3=gval3
```

and the assembled URL is

```
http://localhost/myproject/en/us/controller/action/page/2
```

INSTEAD of

```
http://localhost/myproject/en/us/controller/action/page/2/get1/gval1/get2/gval2/get3/gval3/
```

or (I would prefer the next one)

```
http://localhost/myproject/en/us/controller/action/page/2/?get1=gval1&get2=gval2&get3=gval3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288268/zend-framework-need-to-access-a-get-parameter-from-a-view

Comment: What url are you actually getting and how does it differ from what you are expecting?

Comment: @ilanco , this is not dup, it is not about how to get the value of a parameter, it is about assembling URLs, form existing GET parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course one solution (with Apache) would be to call this in my view:

```
$this->url(array(page=>2)) . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:"")
```

but you cannot be sure this will always be included in the $_SERVER variable.